# Not able to drop button in PyQt6 while implementing Drag and drop Operation

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt6

I am trying a simple drag and drop operation in PyQt6, I just want to drag the button to the middle of the canvas (hopefully within a certain area).. I was able to get the drag operation but not able to drop it in the main window. I'm really new to PyQt6, so sorry if the code is unbearable.. Thank you so much in advance for your help! I appreciate it.

Here's my code!

```
# Import necessary modules
import sys
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QWidget, QLabel,  QPushButton)
from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt, QMimeData, QEvent
from PyQt6.QtGui import QDrag, QPixmap, QPainter, QCursor

class ButtonNew(QPushButton):

    def __init__(self, title, parent):
        super().__init__(title, parent)
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.MouseButton.LeftButton:
            self.drag_start_position = event.pos()
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, e):
        if e.buttons() != Qt.MouseButton.LeftButton:
            return
        if (e.pos() - self.drag_start_position).manhattanLength() < QApplication.startDragDistance():
            return
        # write the relative cursor position to mime data
        drag = QDrag(self)
        mimedata = QMimeData()
        #mimedata.setText('%d,%d' % (e.x(), e.y()))
        
        mimedata.setText(self.text())
        drag.setMimeData(mimedata)
        pixmap = QPixmap(self.size())
        painter = QPainter(pixmap)
        painter.drawPixmap(self.rect(), self.grab())
        painter.end()
        drag.setPixmap(pixmap)
        drag.setHotSpot(e.pos())
        #drag.exec(Qt.CopyAction | Qt.MoveAction)
        drag.exec(Qt.DropAction.MoveAction, Qt.DropAction.MoveAction)

class MainWindow(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initializeUI()
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        
    def initializeUI(self):
        """Set up the application's GUI."""
        self.setGeometry(200, 200, 500, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle("QPushButton Example")
        self.setMinimumSize(500,300)
        #setfixedsize for not changing size
        self.setUpMainWindow()
        self.show()
        
    def dragEnterEvent(self, e):
        e.accept()
  
    def dropEvent(self, e):
       # self.setAcceptDrops(True)
       self.setPixMap(e.pixmap)
    
    def setUpMainWindow(self):
        self.button1 = ButtonNew("Push Me1", self)
        self.button1.move(10, 20)
        self.button1.clicked.connect(self.buttonClicked1)

    def buttonClicked1(self):
        button_Number = "button1_" + str(self.times_pressed1)
        self.button_Number = ButtonNew(button_Number, self)
        self.button_Number.move(90, 20)
        self.button_Number.setDragEnabled(True)
        self.button_Number.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: The `e` object is a [QDropEvent](//doc.qt.io/qt-6/qdropevent.html), not the QDrag instance. Drag and drop uses data serialization (since data has to be shared between different processes), and that data is accessible within the event's `mimeData()`, which allows setting images. I strongly suggest you to read the official [Qt drag and drop documentation](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/dnd.html) to better understand its principles. Also remember to test your code in a terminal or prompt in order to see the full output, as some IDEs are not capable of capturing errors from modules using external libraries.

Comment: Thank you so much for your guidance. I think I somewhat understand what is going on. Also, do you suggest learning c++ to read the documentation?

Comment: No, it's not necessary: in fact, Python syntax has many concepts in common with C++, so if you're fluent in Python you can probably understand most C++ code. If you are also familiar with javascript, it will be even better. Obviously, there are differences. Most importantly, Python passes argument by assignment (the value), while C++ normally does it by reference (the pointer), that's why some PyQt functions have different returned types than their C++ counterparts. C++ is also strictly *typed*, so variables are declared with their type and their values cannot be set to other types.

Comment: You can obviously do some research on the basic C++ principles (and differences with other languages you're used to), but if you're just doing it for research purposes, it's mostly a matter of experience. Start by reading the sources and sooner or later your understanding will certainly improve. Luckily, Qt sources are normally very well written, with a clear syntax and consistent code styling. I suggest you to use the [codebrowser.dev](//codebrowser.dev) website, which has a very nice interface with tooltips and referenced links between various parts of the code.